# FeignBuilder ClassNotFoundException issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I'm getting following exception in a project using OpenFeign. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Exception is given below:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.seamless.ers.links.kyc.client.CustomerDetailsClient': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: feign.Feign$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_301]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Below are the dependencies added:
spring-cloud-starter
spring-cloud-openfeign-core
spring-boot-starter-test
spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: feign.Feign$Builder` Looks like you're missing the `spring-cloud-starter-feign`

Answer (score 0):

Most famous class loading exception and indicates that compiler have difficulties to detect proper dependent class i.e provided the dependency at runtime, following are most healer to issue

- Check the version and probably duplication of your maven artifact for `spring-cloud-starter` -  `spring-cloud-openfeign-core` if you are not using spring boot parent and if the artifacts imported properly from firtplace,
- Check the scope of the dependencies, for the current case in hand the will be **provided** to **compile** `<scope>provided</scope>`
- Exclude the duplicate dependencies that they provide spring feign as transparent dependency .